# Animating gluing a hexagon into a torus

Tags: general-topology

I am looking for a software that allows me to animate the gluing process of turning a hexagon into a torus. My goal is to animate something like this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-be1ABH-ONM

I need the video to have a high resolution, and preferably something that is easier to be used by mathematicians (optional).
Currently I use sagemath with the animate tool, but the output has horrible resolutions, so I am looking for other alternatives.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Does it have to be freeware?

Comment: Freewares or softwares that give a trial period would be preferred, as I am making this on a grad student budget.